# Website and Firefox Plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox-addon

I have created a website that downloads videos from Youtube. But now I want this as a firefox plugin.

I searched in google since last 2 days but hard luck to find the things. So please help me to convert my website code to firefox plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/developers/builder). Here the [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/), and you can also download it from [Github](http://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk).

I would say that the [Getting Started](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html#getting-started) section of Add-on SDK docs is a good place to start your reading.

You can also join the IRC channel #jetpack on irc.mozilla.org and ask help directly to the SDK team, if you have any doubt!